# derive features from date string in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I try to parse a CSV file which contains a date string (format "2018-03-30 09:30:05").

It should be turned into one-hot encoded features in the form of day / hour / minute / second.

One obvious way to do this is using pandas and store in a separate file or HDF store.

But in order to simplify the workflow (and leverage the GPU), I would like to do this directly in TensorFlow.

Assume the date string is on position -2, I thought something like `tf.int32(tf.substr(row[-2],0,4))` should work to get the year, but it returns `TypeError: 'DType' object is not callable`.

```
with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter("train_sample_sorted.tfrecords") as tf_writer:
i = 0
for row in myArray:
    i +=1
    if(i%10000==0):
        print(row[-2])
    #timefeatures = int(row[-2][0:4]) ## TypeError: Value must be iterable
    #timefeatures = tf.int32(tf.substr(row[-2],0,4)) ## TypeError: 'DType' object is not callable
    features, label = row[:-2], row[-1]
    example = tf.train.Example()
    example.features.feature["features"].float_list.value.extend(features)
    example.features.feature["timefeatures"].float_list.value.extend(timefeatures)
    example.features.feature["label"].int64_list.value.append(label)
    tf_writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

What is the best practice to handle date strings as input features? Is there a way around pre-processing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first version `int( row[ -2 ][ 0 : 4 ] )` fails for two reasons: one is that indexing cannot be used on a string tensor's strings, and if it didn't fail for that, it would fail because you cannot convert it to int like that.

The second version `tf.int32( tf.substr( row[ -2 ], 0, 4 ) )` is almost there, it does the string splitting fine, but to convert strings to numbers you have to use [tf.string_to_number](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/string_to_number) you cannot simply cast a string to a number like that with tensors.

Without access to the data you use I couldn't test it, but this should work:

```
tf.string_to_number( tf.substr( row[ -2 ], 0, 4 ), out_type = tf.int32 )
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the first error after activating eager execution. But writing that back with `example.features.feature["timefeatures"].float_list.value.extend(timefeatures)` now runs into `TypeError: Cannot iterate over a scalar tensor.`. How about the general approach? Would you do something like that? Or is feature engineering better done outside TF?

Comment: One small thing first: we're producing an int32 and you're adding it to a float list. Maybe it should be an int64_list (not int32 list available as far as I can tell) and the out_type correspondingly set to int64 as well.

Comment: You said in your question that you're trying to do the conversion to one-hot encoding in TensorFlow to simplify your workflow. TensorFlow is probably quicker and you can prefix a network with this code and you save the conversion, which is particularly useful if you expect the input CSV to change. On the other hand the code might be simpler if you don't use TensorFlow for the conversion. These are the pros and cons.

Comment: The line I wrote creates the tensors, which you can run in a TensorFlow session. You can't use the tensors as pieces of data like that. Sorry for not pointing that out earler. You need to set up a session like `sess = tf.Session()` and then use `time_features_value = sess.run( timefeatures )` to execute the tensor and get the actual value. (This is just a code fragment, you need to feed it with input too.) The whole idea of setting up the tensors is that you don't individually run them, however. Build your network on these tensors and run the whole thing together.